# Insert Object were match array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two array arr1 where qid is  unique and arr2 where markid is unique. I want match qid and markid and result from that result arr3

```
arr1=[subjectwisequetion:[questions:
                                [{qid:"1",anskey:"c"}],
                                [{qid:"2",anskey:"c"}],
                                [{qid:"3", anskey:"c"}]
                        ]
     ]

arr2=[ 
        {markid:"2", markstatus:"2"},
        {markid:"3", markstatus:"1"}
     ]




arr3= [subjectwisequetion:
                        [questions:[
                                    {qid:"1", anskey:"c", markstatus:"null"}
                                   ],
                                   [
                                   {qid:"2", anskey:"c", markstatus:"2"}
                                   ],
                                   [
                                   {qid:"3", anskey:"c" , markstatus:"1"}
                                   ]
                        ]
      ]
```

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code. And, provide us a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. What is `subjectwisequetion`? It is currently not defined.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me:

```
let arr11 = [{qid:"1", anskey:"c"}, {qid:"1",anskey:"c"},{qid:"1", anskey:"c"}]
let arr22 = arr2=[ {markid:"2", markstatus:"2"},{markid:"3", markstatus:"1"}]

let arr33 = arr11.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, arr22[i]));
```